# Changing div stacking layout depending on screen size/orientation in ionic grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I have html structure similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

that should stack bunch of divs in 1 column on small, 2 columns on medium and 4 columns on large screens...

Can someone help me how to do this in ionic framework?

Comment: You need to look into [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

There are some variables to your design that would influence the correct answer here (for example, how you want the vertical stacked DIVs to interact with each other and how you want the content of each to affect the DIV heights). But, in general, this can be accomplished with media queries by responding to the various widths (I chose 2000, 1000, and 700 as the break points) and changing the widths of floating divs:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPKEax

Code dump:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

div {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}

@media (max-width: 2000px) {
  div {
     width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  div {
     width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  div {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of media queries, but i'm looking for out of box solution for ionic, if it exists...